# Получение значений по ключу из JSON

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, requests, response

Отправляю запрос на сайт:

```
response = requests.get('http://localhost/botparking')
```

Получаю JSON:

```
print(response.json())
```

Получаю ответ:

```
[{'id': 4, 'adress': 'ул. Балканская, 26', 'starttime': '09:00:00', 'endtime': '23:00:00', 'minimaltimeforpayment': '3 часа', 'price': 250, 'numberofavailableseats': 250}, {'id': 3, 'adress': 'ул. Ратная, 27', 'starttime': '00:00:00', 'endtime': '23:59:00', 'minimaltimeforpayment': '1 час', 'price': 150, 'numberofavailableseats': 150}]
```

Как мне взять отсюда нужным мне данные (`adress`, например)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

присвойте `response.json()` переменной (`data`, например):

```
data = [{'id': 4, 'adress': 'ул. Балканская, 26', 'starttime': '09:00:00', 'endtime': '23:00:00', 'minimaltimeforpayment': '3 часа', 'price': 250, 'numberofavailableseats': 250}, {'id': 3, 'adress': 'ул. Ратная, 27', 'starttime': '00:00:00', 'endtime': '23:59:00', 'minimaltimeforpayment': '1 час', 'price': 150, 'numberofavailableseats': 150}]
```

и работайте с ней, как со списком словарей:

```
>>> data[0]['adress']
'ул. Балканская, 26'
```

здесь:

- [0] - обращение к первому словарю в списке data;
- ['adress'] - вызов значения словаря с ключом 'adress'

Обходом списка можно добраться до каждого из 'adress':

```
for d in data:
    print(d['adress'])
```

выведет:

```
ул. Балканская, 26
ул. Ратная, 27
```

или сгенерируйте список строк с адресами для дальнейшего использования:

```
addresses = [d['adress'] for d in data]

>>> addresses
['ул. Балканская, 26', 'ул. Ратная, 27']
```

Comment: А как мне получить все адреса в моём JSON? У меня может быть всегда разное количество этих адресов

Comment: @Иван уже обновил ответ